# Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?

Tags: suporte, faq, comportamento, resposta-aceita

Pergunto isso, pois faz uns dias que tenho notado que em algumas perguntas a resposta excelente não é a aceita, e não simplesmente pelo fato de não ser a melhor para o autor, mas sim pela "aceitação" ter sido muito rápida. O que mais me chamou a atenção foi uma pergunta que já havia sido suspensa ter mudado a resposta aceita quase de uma hora pra outra (se bem que aí provavelmente a pergunta estivesse tão ampla que qualquer coisa servia).

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Algumas vezes eu fui ver o feed às 8 da manhã e já tinha resposta do **mesmo dia** marcada como aceita. Embora em alguns casos, quando ela responde resolve diretamente o problema do OP isso até seja válido. Porém, de qualquer forma, sempre acho interessante aguardar, pois uma solução melhor sempre pode surgir.

Comment: @utluiz É, pelo que você comentou realmente não foi só impressão minha :) Talvez no SOzão isso não seja problema, mas no nosso como é novidade pra muita gente, acaba confundindo o usuário novo e atrapalhando até as votações.

Comment: E vejam que eu nem comentei da aceitação da auto-resposta imediatamente, pois esse é um problema mais específico ainda, e não é o foco que eu quis abordar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Definitivamente não

A aceitação é importante, apesar de não ser compulsória. É sempre interessante aceitar a melhor resposta para informar a todos que a solução para o problema foi alcançada.

Não foi imposto um limite de tempo no *engine* justamente porque é prerrogativa do autor da pergunta aceitar a resposta que ele achar melhor, quando ele achar melhor.

A não ser que tenha algo que eu nunca soube ou nunca percebi, a liberdade é total em como fazer a aceitação. Então, estou dizendo o contrário?

Não. Tem maneiras de fazer a aceitação que produzem resultados melhores perante a comunidade e seu próprio interesse específico. Há uma diretriz que todo mundo deveria seguir, apesar de não ser compulsória.

O principal ponto, e que responde sua pergunta, é que a aceitação prematura *quase* impede que outras pessoas postem novas respostas que podem ser até melhores que a aceita. Não impede de fato, mas todo mundo fica um pouco receoso em responder o que já foi solucionado. E depois de aceitar uma resposta, o autor acaba negligenciando outras respostas, que podem inclusive ter sido editadas e melhoradas.

Não podemos fazer muita coisa, mas a recomendação é aguardar até ter várias respostas.

Em alguns casos podemos comentar, principalmente para novatos, sobre o benefício que ele poderia ter em aguardar para aceitar depois. Claro que também corremos o risco dele esquecer. Nem todo mundo percebe que tem um perfil valiosíssimo para ajudar administrar seus ativos no site.

Já vi gente aceitando a primeira resposta postada segundos depois.

Tem esse outro problema da pergunta ampla. De fato elas produzem respostas que podem ser aleatoriamente certas :)

Comment: Eu ia aceitar sua resposta correndo, mas é bom ver a opinião dos outros. </sarcasm>

Comment: Muito comum no SO. O Jon Skeet do SO uma vez falou que uma coisa normal lá é uma pergunta com x upvotes, uma resposta aceita com 2x e uma não aceita com 10x.

Comment: São 2 lados em jogo aí: o que é melhor para o autor e o que é melhor para a comunidade. Eles não são necessariamente conflitantes, obviamente, mas nesse caso aceitar uma resposta de cara pode realmente desincentivar a participação de mais pessoas. Dito isso, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, vá em frente em aceite sem se preocupar com o tempo que passou. Não há necessidade alguma de aceitar uma resposta incompleta, só porque ela foi a primeira ou é a mais votada. Eu recebi melhor resposta pra uma das minhas perguntas 1 mês depois de tê-la feito.