# Posso comentar uma resposta melhor votada, para atrair a atenção pra minha?

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas, comentários

> [Fiz essa pergunta originalmente no metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120926/177950), e não encontrei nenhuma objeção, mas gostaria de saber **desta comunidade** o que as pessoas acham.

Uma vez eu [respondi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120926/177950) uma pergunta feita 3 anos antes, com quase 6 mil visualizações (e crescendo - hoje mais de 20 mil), nenhuma resposta aceita (aparentemente o OP largou o site), e 4 respostas já existentes com votos a favor (mas pelo que pude avaliar nenhuma delas era uma resposta conclusiva à pergunta). A minha resposta também não era conclusiva, mas eu honestamente acreditava que seria útil às pessoas que estivessem com o mesmo problema. Entretanto, por se tratar de uma resposta (muito) tardia, eu acreditava que ninguém iria rolar até o fim da tela onde ela estava, apesar do fato se ser um problema recorrente e ainda não resolvido.

Como minha resposta tinha coisas em comum com a resposta mais votada, eu pensei em comentar nela para atrair a atenção para a minha, mas estava inseguro de fazê-lo. Por um lado, me parece ser uma atitude "sacana", piorada pelo fato de que minha resposta envolvia código que eu mesmo escrevi (seria ela *realmente* uma boa contribuição ou estaria eu só me auto-bajulando?), e a prática é passível de abuso. Por outro lado, o objetivo último desse site é dar grandes respostas para perguntas importantes (para seu público-alvo), e ninguém ganha nada se uma resposta potencialmente útil é obscurecida pelas circunstâncias somente.

Eu poderia simplesmente seguir meu instinto e fazer isso de qualquer forma, ou simplesmente adotar a alternativa "mais segura" de incluir a resposta inteira como um comentário (apagando a original), ou ainda oferecer um [*bounty*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114839/177950) para a pergunta na esperança de que alguém prestasse atenção (apesar do quão bobo me parece - tentar recompensar minha própria resposta *sabendo* que o sistema não vai deixar). Mas eu estou curioso sobre o que a comunidade pensa sobre isso, no caso geral, por isso eu decidi perguntar aqui:

Está tudo bem comentar em uma resposta melhor votada para atrair a atenção para sua própria?

(P.S. no caso de alguém achar que isso é uma manobra para auto-promoção, considere isso: se minha resposta realmente não é útil, é facil pros outros votarem contra até sua obliteração... :P)

---

<sub>**Nota:** fui em frente e coloquei o comentário, e funcionou - consegui 13 votos a favor, levando ela quase pro 2º lugar dentre as perguntas (bom resultado pra uma resposta 3 anos atrasada, não?). Fiz isso algumas vezes aqui no SOPT também, em particular nos casos em que o OP [aceita uma resposta muito rápido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas)...</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Sim a prática é passível de abuso, mas muitas vezes dá para perceber quando há abuso e quando é legítimo.

Eu acho que na maioria das vezes se a pessoa souber como fazer, pode ser vantajoso para todos. mesmo se uma pessoa possa perder a aceitação, ela ainda pode acabar aprendendo com sua resposta.

Como você mesmo disse, tem alternativas para tentar em alguns casos. Mas não sei se precisa ser tão rígido assim de exigir que nada extra possa ser feito.

Se ninguém é contra lá no MSO (onde todo mundo é mais chato :) ), porque seriamos aqui? :)

Penso o mesmo que Shadow Wizard. Você não vai ter tanta vantagem assim, mas se acha que vai dar resultado, por mim ok.

Será que os votos que você recebeu foram devidos ao comentário? Me parece estranho que seja por isso, mas posso não estar vendo algo.

Comment: "Será que os votos que você recebeu foram devidos ao comentário?" Difícil dizer com certeza, a resposta foi dada 19 de Janeiro, o comentário 1 de Fevereiro, e [todos os votos de 1 Fev. pra frente](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/160819?AnswerID=8933546)... (embora eu também tenha **editado** a resposta nesse mesmo dia, após o feedback no meta, isso pode ter elevado a qualidade da resposta; de qq forma, não há signif. estatística) No mais, tenho certeza já ter lido estudos de UX dizendo que os usuários param de rolar a tela a partir de certo ponto, isso deve valer aqui também.

Comment: @mgibsonbr A sorte influencia muita mesmo, fazer a edição no momento certo faz muita diferença para "pegar no tranco". E realmente o barra de rolagem é preguiçosa :)

Comment: Lembrando que muitas vezes nem é o comentário em si, mas o fato de gerar atividade e "puxar" a pergunta pra cima.