# É ruim mudar a resposta aceita?

Tags: debate

Fiz a pergunta [Como determinar qual elemento HTML e/ou qual evento chamou uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7137/como-determinar-qual-elemento-html-e-ou-qual-evento-chamou-uma-funcao) e aceitei uma resposta que resolveu meu problema.

Após aceitá-la, outro usuário veio com uma resposta ainda mais completa e até corrigindo uma determinada passagem em relação ao uso do `this`. Então fica a dúvida, é mal visto pela comunidade aceitar uma resposta e depois mudar a aceitação? Devo esperar mais tempo antes de aceitar uma resposta mesmo que uma delas resolva ou esclareça meu problema na "esperança" de vir uma ainda melhor?

Comment: Eu poderia responder, mas iria parecer que estou puxando a sardinha pro meu lado... ;)

Comment: @utluiz Acho que se você for imparcial em relação a pergunta e se ater somente à situação que pode acontecer com outros usuários e/ou perguntas não vai parecer, pelo menos não pra mim. Só não pensar na pergunta e na resposta, mas sim no contexto da situação, mas de qualquer maneira sinta-se à vontade para responder ou não.

Answer (score 14):

Depende do motivo.

Se a resposta atualmente marcada como certa atende 100% a sua pergunta e está correta, creio que você deva mantê-la como certa, mesmo que uma resposta melhor e mais completa apareça depois. Com raras exceções, creio que o foco da comunidade deve ser em perguntas novas.

Entretanto, se o motivo da mudança for algo como:

- Você percebeu que marcou a primeira resposta precipitadamente
- Você descobriu que a resposta estava errada e o autor não os corrigiu
- Embora a primeira resposta possa ter ajudado, ela não era completa ou era uma "gambiarra"
- Embora a primeira resposta tenha funcionado, a segunda resolve o problema de forma mais eficiente, elegante, simples e assim por diante

Em minha opinião, essas situações tendem a ocorrer mais quando a resposta certa é escolhida muito cedo. Isso é muito relacionado com a questão "[Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/494/227)".

Muitos usuários acessam o site apenas em determinados horários do dia, então minha sugestão para evitar situações como essa é aguardar, no mínimo, 24 horas para aceitar uma resposta e então votar na de melhor qualidade. Se houverem duas melhores respostas equivalentes, eu iria na que foi postada primeiro.

Ainda em minha opinião, existe um outro fator subjetivo que conta muito para a decisão sobre trocar ou não. Às vezes uma resposta é tão boa e completa que a comunidade como um todo "sente" que ela deve ser aceita. Em vários perguntas aqui do SOPT e também do SOEN há comentários do tipo "Esta resposta é a correta".

E, para encerrar, não fique tão preocupado com essa questão sobre mudar a resposta. Alguns usuários respondem perguntas já respondidas não com o intuito de apenas de competir pela aceitação, mas para:

- Prover uma resposta completa e ampla para quem visita o site depois, de modo a servir como uma referência e não apenas resolver um problema pontual
- Complementar algum conceito que não caberia num comentário, por exemplo
- Propor alternativas à solução da primeira resposta

Comment: Excelente resposta, vou começar a praticar não aceitando a sua resposta pra essa pergunta aqui agora. Assim que o sistema começar a me "avisar" pra aceitar uma resposta me pedindo para oferecer recompensa aceitarei a que achar melhor. Obrigado!

Comment: Não concordo. Se apareceu uma resposta que o autor da pergunta acha melhor, não há problema nenhum em trocar a aceita. O foco da comunidade não é somente em perguntas novas, o objetivo aqui é construir um repositório de conteúdos relevantes, independente de quando foram postados. E também não acho que quem pergunta deva ceder a pressões da comunidade. O autor tem total independência para escolher a pergunta que *ele* achar correta. A comunidade aponta sua opinião com votos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se você tivesse postado como resposta eu com certeza estaria em dúvida agora.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu não discordo de você. Porém, minha opinião é que o OP não deve ficar trocando a resposta correta sem um bom motivo. É claro que ele possui *todo o direito* de fazer isso conforme desejar, mas o sistema vai punir isso com alguns pontos negativos. E eu não disse que ele *deve* ceder a pressão da comunidade, mas ele deve considerar isso para uma possível troca, principalmente quando ele está em dúvida. Infelizmente, eu já visitei vários questões no SOEN onde a resposta correta era a pior e só estava marcada porque o OP não sabe usar a plataforma.

Comment: Concordo que ficar trocando de resposta não é uma boa. E sou a favor de esperar um tempo antes de selecionar a resposta, como você sugeriu. @PhilippeGioseffi Em debates aqui no meta você vai ver muitas opiniões divergentes, e nem precisa escolher uma resposta, então, problema resolvido! :)

Answer (score 5):

## Aceitando uma resposta

Uso aqui a mesma tática do que no SOE. *"Muita hora nessa calma"*. De certa maneira existe um instinto que nos leva a querer recompensar aqueles que tomaram tempo para nos ajudar (o que é louvável), mas puxe o gatilho rápido demais e você atirará no próprio pé.

A Sua pergunta é objetiva (deveria, caso contrário melhore sua pergunta)? Ótimo! Vá aplicar as respostas, faça testes, tente pesquisar novas soluções utilizando aquile que você aprendeu com as respostas. No papel de autor da pergunta, use as respostas como ponto de partida para se especializar no assunto. Isso te trará segurança na hora de aceitar uma resposta e abrirá uma janela de tempo para outros usuários responderem.

Procure confirmar que a resposta está correta. Se ela está correta, *up vote*; se está parcialmente correta ou te ajudou a chegar na resposta, *up vote* e comentário; se não está correta, *down vote* e comentário.

Dessa forma, quando você finalmente aceitar uma resposta terá bastante segurança que ela é a "melhor" para o seu problema.

## Quando aceitar uma resposta?

Qual é o tempo certo? 24 horas? Uma semana? Não importa, não se sinta pressionado, aceite a resposta quando tiver resolvido seu problema e se sentindo **100% seguro** que aquela resposta é a "melhor" para o contexto da pergunta.

## Mas e depois?

É claro que as respostas envelhecem, novas alternativas surgem e alguns programadores investem muito tempo em criar respostas completíssimas.

Eu concordo com o @utluiz que o foco da comunidade deve estar nas novas perguntas, mas se alguém tomou tempo de responder sua pergunta muitos dias depois, tome tempo para "dar manutenção". Você é a melhor pessoa para julgar essas respostas... Vote e comente nelas :)

## Trocando de resposta

O que está sendo discutido aqui é se você deve ou não trocar a resposta aceita.

Sabendo que as coisas são mutáveis; que temos mecanismos como comentários, votos e medalhas (como a raríssima [Populista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist)) para incentivar respostas melhores / mais atuais; eu acredito que só devemos trocar respostas em casos **extremos**. Então respondendo sua pergunta, **sim**, na minha opinião é ruim trocar de respostas.

Dito isso providências devem ser tomadas em alguns casos:

- A resposta introduziu um bug que você não conseguiu detectar inicialmente (esse bug está na resposta e não em outros lugares da sua aplicação)
- A resposta usa uma estratégia absolutamente errada para resolver o problema
- A resposta funcionou por "coincidência" ou devido a restrições não especificadas na pergunta e nos comentários.
- A resposta está misturando conceitos e pode levar outros usuários do site a terem problemas

## Como devo agir nesses casos?

O principal objetivo deve ser melhorar a resposta e não punir o autor.

Eu pessoalmente, faria um comentário e daria uma chance para o autor original atualizar a resposta antes de aceitar uma nova resposta. Se o autor da resposta original não se manifestar e nenhum outro autor o fizer, eu escreveria minha própria resposta sem o mínimo de vergonha.

## O que representa a resposta aceita?

Eu acredito que a resposta aceita sirva como um registro histórico, uma fotografia. A resposta aceita representa aquilo que resolveu o seu problema naquela exato momento e contexto, utilizando as melhores práticas e o que estava disponível na época.

## E as outras respostas?

Com o tempo perguntas populares se tornam repositórios de informação sobre determinado problema. Conforme a tecnologia e compreensão sobre melhores práticas evoluem novas respostas são escritas. Essas são aquelas respostas que começam com *"Eu entendo que essa é uma pergunta antiga, porém...."*

Além disso, uma resposta mais completa e mesmo tecnicamente mais correta não necessariamente é a mais prática ou mais apropriada para o contexto.

Veja a pergunta **[Como inverter uma string em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5943/como-inverter-uma-string-em-javascript/5952#5952)**. A resposta mais correta e foi a mais votada (e de quebra ganhou a gratificação), porém, para todo um domínio de entradas a resposta aceita - bem mais simples - é suficiente. Os comentários indicam claramente quais são os "problemas" com a resposta aceita, logo, ela é de grande valia para a comunidade. Eu estou para postar uma resposta alternativa com uma biblioteca feita especialmente para inverter strings, porém não acho que esta deve ser a resposta aceita (poucas pessoas vão incluir uma biblioteca apenas para inverter strings, a não ser que precisem disso para um uso altamente especializado).

## Mas isso não é injusto com quem tomou tempo para elaborar uma resposta melhor?

Enquanto cada um é cada um. Para mim os pontos são o que menos importam. Eu vejo o SO como o Drew Carey Show (sim, eu sou velho): *"Um lugar onde os pontos não importam"*. O que realmente importa é que respostam são indexadas pelo Google e diversas pessoas vão ter acesso a esse conteúdo. Não quero entrar em detalhes sobre a utilidade do sistema de pontos e reputação no stack overflow (que é simplesmente uma medida de confiança)... Apenas penso que a principal motivação para escrever uma boa resposta é registrá-la onde ela fique visível. Votos são mais do que suficientes para tornar uma resposta visível. Ter suas resposta aceita é apenas um prêmio para aqueles que conseguiram fazer isso a tempo de atender a demanda do autor da pergunta.

**Resumindo:**

- Tome tempo para aceitar suas respostas
- Não se preocupe em aceitar uma resposta que posteriormente venha a se tornar defasada. As coisas mudam
- Se você aceitou uma resposta e posteriormente descobriu que ela estava errada, notifique o autor e dê uma chance para que ele corrija a resposta
- Mude a resposta se você percebeu que ela não resolveu o seu problema
- Mude de resposta se você achar que a resposta aceita poderá prejudicar outros programadores
- Não mude de resposta por que existe uma resposta "mais correta" ou "mais atual"
- A resposta mais correta não é necessariamente a que resolveu seu problema
- Vote e comente sempre!