# É correto retirar o aceite da resposta de um usuário e colocar na minha, que foi derivada da resposta dele, ainda que a minha seja mais completa?

Tags: debate, resposta-aceita

Há uns dias atrás eu fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/527350/157404) no site e um usuário me respondeu. Como estava correta e me ajudou, eu aceitei a resposta.

Depois de um tempo, eu pesquisei um pouco mais sobre o assunto e criei a minha própria resposta, derivada da resposta dele. Agora a minha resposta está mais completa.

Dito isso, eu estou em um dilema: é correto ou não retirar o aceite da resposta dele e colocar na minha? Pois se não fosse pela resposta dele, eu não teria criado a minha própria resposta.

Comment: Por mim não se acanhe, fique à vontade para aceitar sua resposta, até porque certamente outros usuários no futuro poderão ser beneficiados por ter uma referência mais detalhada em destaque.

Comment: Bom, pronto, acho que seu dilema moral está resolvido. Em termos de organização do site é interessante que a resposta mais completa esteja marcada como aceita. Mas eu entendo o receio de fazer a troca num caso como este.

Comment: Creio que seja bom esperar antes de fazer qualquer coisa. Tem uma proposta de que o aceito não mude mais a ordenação das perguntas, se for pra frente, o que vai importar são os votos, e o accept "honorário" pode ficar na original (nesse caso, se o accept ficar na sua resposta, não vai pinar ela em cima pela pergunta também ser sua, mas com a mudança proposta, o accept na original também passará a não influenciar na ordem).

Comment: Seria uma tremenda injustiça da sua parte. Parta do princípio que nem sempre a resposta com ✔ é a melhor, ainda mais que a sua resposta foi baseada na do outro, sem contar que foi vc mesmo quem fez a pergunta. Opinião: inclua na sua resposta um texto informando que a sua resposta foi inspirada na outra.

Comment: Mts vezes (acho que a maioria das vezes) quando pesquiso alguma solução no site pra uma dificuldade minha, a solução que acho melhor não é a que foi marcada com ✔. Deve ter um tópico aí que trata disso, que nem sempre a resposta ✔ é a melhor.

Comment: Só pra constar, a proposta que o Bacco mencionou está sendo discutida aqui: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/401803 - já sobre a pergunta, depende muito, mas falando **de forma mais geral**, se surgiu uma resposta melhor (mais completa, correta, etc - ou seja, com mais qualidade), não tem problema nenhum mudar o aceite (é até desejável/recomendado, dado o objetivo do site de ser um repositório de conhecimento onde a qualidade é - ou pelo menos deveria ser - o mais importante). Mas se houve plágio ou algo do tipo, aí é sacanagem mesmo. Enfim, tem que ver caso a caso...

Comment: No seu caso, se vc pesquisou mais sobre o assunto (mesmo que tenha usado a outra resposta como ponto de partida) e se aprofundou no tema, então houve esforço da sua parte e a princípio não seria um grande problema mudar o aceite. Se vc só "copiou" e acrescentou pouca coisa (sendo que "pouca" é subjetivo), aí não seria justo com a outra resposta. Resumindo, minha resposta está entre o "não sei" e o "depende". No fim, a decisão de qual resposta aceitar sempre é de quem pergunta, e os demais não têm muito o que fazer a respeito...

Comment: Acabei de ver que já tivemos discussão nesse sentido, segue link: [É ruim mudar a resposta aceita?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/950/70)

Comment: @hkotsubo acho importante alguém (_wink wink_) trazer pro nosso meta a discussão do accept não influenciar na ordenação, para que possamos adotar a ordenação por votos logo de início se a comunidade aprovar.

Comment: @Bacco Tá lá: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8662/112052

Comment: A sacanagem é que o AP não ganha nenhuma pontuação, e o outro usuário perde 15pts, ou seja, o AP está literalmente desmerecendo a resposta do outro usuário tirando os pontos dele.

Comment: Não vá na onda da opinião de usuários antigos e poderosos não. Siga seu instinto de justiça. Vc acha justo tirar 15pts do usuário que lhe deu a resposta? Seja independente em julgar seus critérios pessoais.

Comment: Não é justo não. Estou falando isso desde o meu primeiro comentário.

Comment: Parabéns! Fez a coisa certa e ganhou meu voto +1.

Comment: Se está preocupado com a "injustiça" de tirar os pontos (concordo em partes, pois cada caso é um caso), vc poderia aceitar sua resposta e dar uma recompensa para a outra (é uma opção quando tem 2 respostas muito boas e vc não sabe qual aceitar, por exemplo, mas também serviria pro seu caso, pra "reparar a injustiça"). Enfim, a pergunta é sua e só vc pode decidir qual resposta aceitar, mas tem que pensar também no objetivo do site: as respostas devem servir não só pra vc, mas também para futuros visitantes. Idealmente, as melhores respostas deveriam ficar acima das demais...

Comment: ...independente de quem escreveu. Como eu já disse, tem casos e casos (se houve plágio descarado, etc), mas de forma geral isso deveria ser o critério para escolher qual aceitar (não tem nada a ver com seguir o que determinado usuário disse, e sim com as diretrizes gerais sobre como o site funciona - ou pelo menos, como deveria idealmente funcionar). Mas claro que a decisão final é sua (e isso, inclusive, também faz parte do funcionamento do site, por isso só estou orientando e tentando ver todos os lados, em vez de te "obrigar" a fazer algo)

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 faça o que é justo. Você acha que a sua resposta realmente é a melhor? Dê a aceitação para sua resposta. Não dê a aceitação para uma resposta que é pior só porque foi outra pessoa que deu. Isso é injusto com todos, não só com você. Justiça não é dar esmola, a aceitação só deve ser dada para oque é o mais merecido (voto você pode dar para todos que merecem), não tem regra, nem ética estabelecendo que trocar a aceitação para algo melhor. Ruim é você trocar ou só tirar a aceitação para retaliar alguém. Isso dá punição. E mais, os bons usuários não vão querer esmolas, parece o caso

Comment: Dar aceitação como esmola é errado e só não cabe punição porque não tem jurisprudência, e claro, porque a pessoa pode mentir em vários casos. Pense na comunidade. Você pode ser egoísta sendo altruísta, o bem maior é mais importante que o bem para alguém. Mas reforço o que já foi dito, a decisão é sua. Se for injusto com um, com você ou com todos, será você que decidiu.

Comment: O foco não devem ser os pontos, pontos são apenas consequencias, o sistema de gamefication é para incentivar as pessoas a participarem, mas nunca deve ser o foco, o AR perder 15pts não é nada demais, você ainda pode dar upvote pra ele. Você deve pensar é na qualidade da resposta, se a resposta que pretende marcar como aceita for a sua própria (self-answer) ou até uma nova resposta de outro usuário e ela for de fato melhor em **quesitos técnicos de documentação**, então você deve sim alternar.

Comment: Se fosse "incorreto" nem existiria a possibilidade de você responder a própria pergunta ou alternar a resposta aceita por uma nova. Então é justo sim a troca de resposta aceita, é justo com todos, não só com a maioria, porque como disse antes, o foco é a qualidade da postagem e fornecer uma resposta de qualidade é mais importante que pontos. O site não é feito para fornecer "suporte técnico gratuito" e compartilhando/trocando upvotes como se fosse like do facebook ou youtube para agradar pessoas, você deve olhar para o conteudo e não para o indivíduo que postou a resposta.

Comment: O que não é justo é criar dogmas emocionais num site de conteúdo técnico onde se objetiva a veracidade e a qualidade do conhecimento difundido. Se hoje começarmos a negar a aceitação da melhor resposta por comiseração para com os outros autores, amanhã estaremos distribuindo upvotes para qualquer absurdo que publicarem e consequentemente estaremos abolindo os downvotes por pena, como alguns já o querem fazer.