# Devemos mudar a ordenação das respostas, não afixando a resposta aceita antes das demais?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, resposta-aceita

Atualmente (setembro/2021), uma resposta marcada como aceita é afixada (aparece antes de todas as outras), mesmo que tenha menos votos (exceto quando [for uma resposta do próprio autor da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)). Na verdade, se escolhermos outros critérios de ordenação ("Ativos" ou "Mais antigo"), a resposta aceita sempre aparece antes das demais (e somente estas são ordenadas de acordo com o critério escolhido).

Porém, recentemente (08/09/2021), o [Stack Overflow em Inglês (SOen) mudou esta regra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352) e passou a ignorar a aceitação ao ordenar as respostas (**é importante ler para saber as motivações e outros detalhes sobre esta mudança**). Agora, todas as respostas (aceitas ou não) são exibidas de acordo com o critério de ordenação escolhido.

No mesmo dia foi [anunciado no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/401803) que isto poderá ser aplicado aos outros sites da rede. Mas para isso, cada site deve decidir se quer ou não esta mudança. **O propósito desta pergunta é decidir isso**.

As perguntas que seriam impactadas com essa mudança podem ser vistas por meio [desta *query*](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1458833/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer) feita no SEDE (obtida através de um comentário em [uma das respostas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369637/818993) ao anúncio). Neste exato momento, o site tem mais de 150 mil perguntas, e a query indica que cerca de 3600 perguntas seriam afetadas pela mudança (ou seja, cerca de 2,4% das perguntas).

---

## O Stack Overflow em Português deve mudar a ordenação das respostas, não afixando a resposta aceita antes das demais?

O trecho abaixo é uma tradução do [anúncio no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/401803):

> A ordenação das respostas pode ser configurada para cada site.
> Gostaríamos de saber se vocês gostariam de ter isso no seu site (já
> adianto que não será possível conduzir um teste para cada site).
>
> Atualmente estamos considerando um dos cenários abaixo, de acordo com
> o *feedback*:
>
> 1. Não afixar a resposta aceita em nenhum dos sites, e só deixá-la afixada nos poucos sites que pedirem para deixar assim.
> 2. Manter da forma que está (resposta aceita afixada, antes das demais) em todos os sites, e só mudar nos sites que pedirem.
>
> Diga-nos o que você acha melhor para o site. Coletaremos os
> *feedbacks* até o dia 19/09/2021.

Claro que os itens 1 e 2 são meros detalhes de implementação (se a opção *default* é afixar ou não), mas de qualquer forma temos que decidir se queremos deixar como está (resposta aceita afixada) ou mudar (ordenação ignora a aceitação).

---

Como é de praxe (votos no Meta indicam concordo/discordo, etc), podemos considerar a votação desta pergunta como a resposta "oficial" da comunidade (além, é claro, da votação nas eventuais respostas que surgirem), sendo que **votos positivos indicam que você é favor de mudar, e votos negativos indicam que você acha que deve deixar como está**.

Sugiro também - até para ter mais embasamento - ler o [anúncio oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/401803) já citado acima, pois lá já tem várias respostas e comentários discutindo o assunto, e também o [anúncio no SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352), que explica as motivações e tem links para outras discussões (como o teste que foi feito antes da mudança, entre outros detalhes).

---

*PS: Como eu não posso votar na minha própria pergunta, deixo indicado aqui que sou a favor da mudança.*

---

**Atualização:** conforme informado no [anúncio oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/401803), a mudança já foi implementada.

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130089/discussion-on-question-by-hkotsubo-devemos-mudar-a-ordenacao-das-respostas-nao) - para ler ou acrescentar algo, basta utilizar o link fornecido.