# Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?

Tags: debate, perguntas, proposta-para-faq, resposta-aceita

- Como fazer para aceitar uma resposta à minha pergunta?
- Quando devo fazer isso, e por quê?
- Por que não posso aceitar uma resposta imediatamente?
- Qual resposta devo aceitar?

> Para mais informações, ver "[O que devo fazer quando alguém responder à minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

---

<sup>Esta pergunta e sua resposta são uma tradução adaptada das [postagens semelhantes no MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).</sup>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?

Aceitar uma resposta é importante pois deixa claro aos demais usuários que seu problema está resolvido, e como foi resolvido. Ao mesmo tempo, recompensa o autor da melhor resposta por ter resolvido seu problema.

- Você pode selecionar qualquer uma das respostas à sua pergunta como a resposta "aceita". Somente uma resposta na pergunta pode estar marcada como aceita.
- Por um período de [15 minutos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer) após a postagem a pergunta, você não pode aceitar nenhuma resposta.
- Para marcar uma resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo da resposta; sua cor mudará de cinza para verde.
- É possível trocar a resposta aceita, ou mesmo desmarcar uma resposta como aceita, a qualquer momento e quantas vezes for necessário. Mas lembre-se: não é preciso ter pressa nem para aceitar, nem para trocar!

[image: screenshot da interface de aceitação]

Ao aceitar:

- *a resposta de outra pessoa*: você ganha **+2** pontos de reputação, e o autor da resposta ganha **+15** pontos de reputação. A resposta aceita é exibida logo depois da pergunta, mesmo que outras respostas tenham mais votos.
- *sua própria resposta*: você não ganha nenhum ponto, e a resposta não vai para o topo da lista; você só pode aceitar sua própria resposta 48 horas após a postagem da pergunta.
- *uma resposta do tipo "wiki da comunidade"*: ninguém ganha pontos, mas a resposta vai para o topo da lista.

#### Qual resposta devo aceitar?

- Não hesite em aceitar uma resposta bem escrita, que sugere boas práticas e funciona para você.
- Caso não haja nenhuma resposta que te atenda integralmente, sugere-se esperar de 24 a 48 horas, aumentando a chance de alguém postar uma resposta melhor. Perguntas com resposta aceita são menos propensas a receber atenção que perguntas que ainda não têm resposta aceita. Ver também: [Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas)
- Tenha em mente que futuros visitantes com problemas parecidos verão a resposta aceita, e muitas vezes irão ignorar as demais. Portanto tente averiguar se a resposta que você está aceitando não contém erros, hacks ou más-práticas.
- **No fim das contas, a decisão sobre qual resposta aceitar é inteiramente sua.**

#### Votando a favor

- Se uma reposta te ajudou a resolver seu problema, considere dar um voto positivo a ela, seja ela a resposta aceita ou não.

#### E se nenhuma resposta resolve meu problema?

- Releia sua pergunta criticamente, e certifique-se de que a descrição do problema esteja clara. Talvez seja o caso de editar a pergunta para deixá-la mais clara, ou acrescentar um parágrafo ou frase final resumindo o que está sendo perguntado.
- Releia as respostas. Pode ser o caso de aceitar a melhor delas, mesmo que nenhuma seja exatamente o que você está buscando.
- Aguarde alguns dias após perguntar, e edite a pergunta com o que foi aprendendo desde que a postou. Cada edição na pergunta a leva de volta à home do site, aumentando as chances de quem alguém a veja e responda.
- Se você tem mais de 75 pontos de reputação, é possível [colocar uma recompensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) na pergunta, a partir de dois dias após a postagem. A possibilidade de ganhar pontos extras incentiva muita gente a responder.
- Se você finalmente conseguir resolver sozinho o seu problema, poste uma resposta com essa informação, detalhando a solução o melhor possível, e marque sua própria resposta como aceita; isso pode beneficiar outras pessoas que estiverem passando pelo mesmo problema.