# O que fazer quando não se sabe a resposta correta?

Tags: debate, resposta-aceita

Eu tenho aqui um caso, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14774/7210), tenho duas respostas que são um bocado o contrário uma da outra.

**Quando temos respostas contrárias, aceitamos uma das respostas? Esperamos a ver se mais alguém responde? Ou deixamos sem visto de resposta certa?**

É porque eu não faço a menor ideia qual das duas está certa, ainda estou com muitas dúvidas nessa pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se as respostas atuais não te satisfazem, então realmente não faz sentido escolher uma como certa. O ideal é deixá-las em aberto mesmo, pelo tempo que for necessário até surgirem respostas melhores e/ou as respostas atuais forem editadas de modo a resolverem a sua dúvida.

Outra opção é oferecer uma recompensa. O motivo pode variar, dependendo de como você enxerga a situação:

- "Essa pergunta não recebeu atenção suficiente" - se você acha que poucas pessoas chegaram a pelo menos ler sua pergunta, e que um público maior provavelmente trará respostas melhores.
- "As respostas atuais não contém detalhes suficientes" - se você acha que o quadro geral já está bem coberto, mas precisa-se melhorar nas questões específicas (seja através da edição das respostas já existentes, seja por meio de novas respostas).
- "Buscando uma resposta elaborada a partir de fontes oficiais e/ou confiáveis" - se você não tem como avaliar se dada resposta está correta ou não, a menos que seja corroborada por terceiros (de preferência, alguém autoritativo no assunto). Se você tem respostas conflitantes, pode ser o caso de se pedir um rigor maior na citação de fontes.

Lembrando sempre que, com ou sem recompensa, você não tem a *obrigação* de aceitar nenhuma resposta. É de bom tom fazê-lo quando se está satisfeito com elas, tanto para marcar a pergunta como "respondida" quanto para gratificar o autor da resposta pelo seu esforço em ajudá-lo. Mas não é uma obrigação sua.

Para mais informações, veja ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/215), em especial a seção no final "E se nenhuma resposta resolve meu problema?".