# Em caso de mais de uma resposta correta, qual deve ser aceita?

Tags: debate

No SOpt, se tiver mais de uma resposta correta, mais ou menos a mesma coisa, e bem explicadas, qual devemos marcar como aceita? A primeira? Ou isso não tem regra?

Comment: Acredito que não há regra sobre isso. Veja a que mais lhe agradou e aceite. Dar *up-vote* nas outras também já ajudará bastante os outros usuários.

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/494/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2125/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/950/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1312/101.

Comment: Eu vou na que mais me agrada, se der empate, a primeira...

Comment: Defina os critérios que, para si, uma boa resposta deve ter. Com base neles escolha a melhor, aquela que cumpre mais desses critérios. Se não conseguir decidir, escolher a primeira parece-me um critério aceitável.

Comment: Eu marco a que estiver melhor escrita.