# Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, resposta-aceita

Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17548/interpretacao-de-um-algoritmo-em-c) o autor da pergunta escreveu um comentário agradecendo a minha resposta mas não aceitou a mesma.

Escrevi um comentário solicitando que o fizesse, foi minha atitude correta?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Concordo com ambas as respostas. Em resumo, minha sugestão é:

1. Não pressione o OP
2. Analise o perfil para inferir se ele já sabe usar o sistema (embora em alguns casos ele possa simplesmente esquecer de aceitar a resposta)
3. Espere
4. Espere
5. Espere
6. Adicione um comentário dizendo que se o problema foi resolvido ou a dúvida sanada, que por favor escolha a resposta que ele considera mais adequada, obviamente indicando a página da central de ajuda.

O que eu tento não fazer é puxar a sardinha para o meu lado ou mesmo pressionar:

> Se a **minha** resposta ajudou marque-a como certa.

Não que seja um grande pecado, mas não considero ético, pois pode induzir o OP a tomar uma ação sem que ele esteja certo disso, talvez por medo de parecer rude.

Há ainda situações onde o próprio OP comenta informando que o problema foi resolvido e agradecendo. Nesse caso você pode comentar algo assim:

> Ótimo! Já que as respostas lhe foram úteis, não esqueça de escolher uma como certa.

A escolha é sempre do usuário, mesmo que você considere a sua resposta "mais correta" do que as demais.

Comment: Ótimo, sintetizou bem a coisa toda!

Comment: Por vezes, por preguiça, uso "Se a minha resposta ajudou marque-a como certa." mesmo... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51369/grid-system-bootstrap/51394#comment104576_51394

Comment: Boas dicas....,

Answer (score 12):

Se você tem indícios de que o usuário não aceitou por não saber como operar o sistema, pode linkar para [esta página da Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Porém, eu aguardaria um pouco mais para fazer isso. A pergunta que você citou acabou de ser reaberta, e é preciso dar tempo para que apareçam mais respostas (a presença de resposta aceita tende a desencorajar novas respostas).

Só é preciso tomar muito cuidado para não pressionar o usuário. Tem gente que prefere inclusive deixar a situação como está, e muitas vezes outra pessoa acaba orientando o usuário sobre como aceitar. Não que seja proibido fazer o que você fez, mas a pessoa pode se sentir pressionada.

Comment: Exato, o menos invasivo é deixar que outros façam o comentário.

Comment: Eu costumo pedir para o usuário aceitar qualquer resposta quando percebo que ele não entende o sistema, sempre depois de passar bastante tempo (dias, semanas) e preferencialmente quando tem outras respostas além da minha.

Answer (score 10):

> *se a resposta foi util, peço que clique em aceitar resposta.*

#### Não.

Esse tipo de comentário é "não construtivo".

Primeiro confira no perfil do usuário se ele/a já aceitou uma resposta antes. Caso afirmativo, não há nada a se fazer. E seu comentário é passível de ser sinalizado e removido por um moderador.
O que faço num caso assim é buscar outra pergunta onde aconteceu a mesma coisa e fazer o comentário abaixo.

Se nunca aceitou uma resposta, faça um comentário educacional, linkando para a Pergunta/Resposta relevante aqui do Meta:

> Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: Sim, **não**, mas em termos :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim, porém com jeitinho ;) Se não é "mendigagem de pontos"... temos tradução praquele horroroso *rep-whore*?

Comment: Não temos tradução, mas agora você me instigou a procurar algo "criativo"...

Comment: Nem **sim**, nem **não**, muito pelo contrário!

Comment: @Andrey, e eu achando que tinha escrito uma coisa séria =D

Comment: Já adicionei no meu script de comentários :)