# Como ensino um usuário a votar e aceitar minha resposta?

Tags: debate

Eu queria mostrar a alguns usuários a evitar comentar, pois têm muitas respostas que vejo diariamente mas não recebe seu devido valor pelo \ seu esforço.

Eu já passei por isso duas vezes, fiquei 1h investigando o problema e quando coloquei a resposta ele só disse "obrigado", achei muito ruim passar por essa situação.

Eu quero ensinar a eles como dar votar adequadamente, mas não achei um lugar que ensina.

Comment: Relacionado: [Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1425/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo Não. Eu quero mostrar o usuário que quando alguém resolver seu erro dar solucionada.

Comment: Maury, o título da sua pergunta é *"Como ensino um usuário a votar e **aceitar** minha resposta"*, e a pergunta que indiquei tem relação com esse assunto (lá discutem se devemos comentar dizendo para a pessoa aceitar a resposta, em que casos é aceitável, como fazer, etc). Pode não responder exatamente 100% da sua pergunta, mas é um assunto relacionado (por isso eu escrevi "Relacionado") :-)

Comment: Quando falei minha resposta eu falei de qualquer um. Eu uso "eu" pra nós e "minha" para nossa

Comment: De qualquer forma, a pergunta que indiquei é um assunto relacionado, independente da resposta ser sua ou de outra pessoa...

Comment: Você está aqui no SOpt desde quando? Eu gostei de você.

Comment: Acho que isso é o que você quer: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6972/132

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A princípio, aceitar a resposta como correta já é o correto de se *agradecer*, mas isso não impede que outras formas de gratidão sejam proibidas na comunidade, por mais que não sejam adequadas a nossa política.

O intuito desta comunidade Q&A é simplesmente **perguntar e responder**, a reputação é apenas um número onde indica uma relação de como a comunidade recebeu suas publicações, seja perguntas ou respostas. Não somos obrigados a votar, mas é a nossa forma de expressar o que sentimos em relação a certa publicação. O voto é um tanto emotivo quanto racional.

Não é errado apresentar aos usuários novos o **[Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)**, é recomendado na verdade, e exibido quando um novo cadastro é apresentado ao site. Muitas vezes o Tour é introduzido por membros já estabelecidos que tentam ajudar perguntas que muitas vezes são fechadas por não seguir nossas políticas e regras.

Nossos moderadores não podem aceitar respostas corretas, por mais que o OP (*original poster*) foi lá e comentou na sua resposta *"Deu certo, obrigado!"* e deixou ela ali, sem voto e sem reputação.

### Mas afinal, qual era a sua intenção ao responder?

Se for considerar que você queria **ajudar a pessoa**, irá se contentar em receber um comentário do tipo. Qualquer sinal de que a sua resposta deu certo naquela situação irá te confortar, pois você concluiu o que queria.

Agora se a intenção foi por reputação, em crescer seus números, dificilmente essa comunidade irá se adequar a você, não pela plataforma StackOverflow, mas pelos eventuais casos que ocorrem, como os que foram mencionados por você.

Não é errado mencionar o comentário destas pessoas quando elas não aceitam suas respostas, pois assim, você irá instruir ela a como se adaptar a comunidade nas suas futuras perguntas, e assim, ela irá saber lidar com as respostas adequadamente.

Portanto, o mais ideal a fazer, é apresentar a ela o Tour.

O comentário indicado, é mostrar ao OP que ele pode aceitar a sua, como as demais respostas como correta.

> Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).
>
> <sub>Maniero [nesta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7891/24529) resposta</sub>

Comment: Eu não disse que respondo por causa de reputação,mas um +1 é uma gratidão reconhecido seu esforço. Se eu ligasse pra reputação,nem estaria aqui,eu gosto de responde... Mas tem pessoa que pensa diferente.

Answer (score 8):

Vou aproveitar e falar de uma forma geral de algumas coisas. Percebo uma visão equivocada sua do que é o Stack Overflow, alguns comentários seus tem sido sinalizados porque eles não são muito construtivos. Então evite comentar se não tiver certeza do que está falando. O SO deve ter pouco ruído, mu itos comentários seus são ruído e não ajudam o fluxo normal, pense duas vezes antes de comentar.

> Eu queria mostrar a alguns usuários a evitar comentar

Mostre a si mesmo em primeiro lugar.

> pois têm muitas respostas que vejo diariamente mas não recebe seu devido valor pelo \ seu esforço

Isso acontece, mas algumas eu não sei se devem ter esse "devido" valor reconhecido, porque elas talvez não tenham o valor que acha que tem. Posso dizer isto por ver algumas respostas e comentários seus que estão errados. Em resposta é bom porque pode-se negativar, em comentário não pode então as pessoas podem achar que aquilo é certo. Em alguns casos não é errado, só não fala nada do que é esperado ali, é algo quase aleatório.

> Eu já passei por isso duas vezes, fiquei 1h investigando o problema e quando coloquei a resposta ele só disse "obrigado"

Pode ser que a pessoa só agradeceu por ter se esforçado, pode ser que nem resolveu a questão dela. Pode ser que respondeu e tenha outra que a pessoa gostou mais. Pode ser que a pessoa não saiba o que fazer. Essas coisas acontecem.

> achei muito ruim passar por essa situação.

É ruim sim, muito eu não sei, mas só é ruim se a resposta é boa, é a única ou melhor e deveria ser aceita, nem sempre é o caso, não vou repetir o que disse antes.

> Eu quero ensinar a eles como dar votar adequadamente, mas não achei um lugar que ensina.

Votar é diferente de aceitar.

Eu tenho 3 comentários enlatados que uso para indicar para as pessoas que não aceitaram alguma resposta **depois** de um tempo, não falo logo em seguida que a pessoa perguntou e eu respondi, a não ser que ela diga obrigado e percebo que ela não entende, aí eu adapto um dos três. Obviamente só posto isto se nenhuma for aceita e tiver alguma chance da pessoa aceitar, se eu perceber que a pessoa nem sabe o que perguntou, não saberá  escolher uma resposta, é preciso muito bom senso para fazer isto . Acha que tem esse bom senso? Se não tiver vai arrumar confusão.

Quando a pessoa é experiente e só deve ter esquecido:

> A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Tem uma variação que o "A", vira "Alguma" para dar chance para a pessoa escolher uma outra resposta que não seja a minha.

Quando tem algumas respostas de usuário iniciante no site:

> Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Se a pessoa tiver pelo menos 15 pontos tiro os parenteses finais.

Se a minha for a única resposta:

> A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Também tiro o final se a pessoa já tiver a pontuação.

É preciso tomar muito cuidado para não virar algo tendencioso ou até achaque.

Se pedir uma aceitação em coisa errada pode gerar uma saia justa, poderá ser sinalizado, pode complicar a situação no site. Pode ocorrer com todo mundo, mas se acontecer com frequência isso é um problema. Estou reforçando isso pela observação do que responde e já vi pedindo aceitação em coisa errada. Pense bem se vai fazer isso.

Comment: Meu comentário visa adaptar situações de *"isso respondeu minha dúvida, mas vou agradecer por comentários."* e indicar para a comunidade que aquela resposta serviu para a pergunta. Se não comentar (e mencionar) o suposto agradecimento, como o OP irá lidar com as futuras perguntas? Eu digo, uma vez que não soube marcar a resposta como correta, o que irá indicar que deve fazer isso?

Comment: Olha os comentários que eu uso, tem um tom imparcial, o seu tem um tom "marque a minha resposta aí"

Comment: Entendi agora o que quis dizer. Vou complementar seu comentário na minha resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Eu sei que respondo ruins as vezes,porque as vezes a pergunta é tão confusa,que me confundi. @Maniero

Comment: Não responda perguntas ruins, sinalize pra fechar.