# Mensagem de destaque para aceitar respostas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, resposta-aceita

Em algumas situações já devemos ter tido a experiência de uma resposta correta não ser marcada como correta. As vezes o OP até comenta na nossa resposta agradecendo, mas não aceita. Isso nos leva a [pedir para aceitar a resposta como correta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/devemos-pedir-para-aceitar-resposta), não por motivos gananciosos mas até pela qualidade de conteúdo da comunidade, onde **y** responde corretamente à **x**.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447324/24529) tive algo novo: o OP não sabia onde ficava o botão de aceitar a resposta, no comentário dele, dizia que "procurei muito", acredito que disse sobre o botão de aceitação.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Prestem atenção nos comentários. O que eu suponho fazer é mostrar uma mensagem destacada ao usuário novo, dizendo onde ele deve aceitar a resposta.

O que temos hoje é uma mensagem que aparece somente se ele vota positivamente na resposta. Acredito que deveria existir um aviso onde não requer qualquer interação ao ver as postagens. Isso seria útil para aceitação de respostas.

Portanto, minha sugestão é: uma mensagem, onde é exibida a usuários novos em suas perguntas já respondidas, dizendo que se a resposta soluciona a pergunta em questão, deverá ser marcada no botão bem destacado na tela.

Comment: Já vi muitas respostas que resolviam o problema e o OP não sabia onde marcar como solução e deixava comentário. Muito boa a idéia.

Comment: Seria bom, mas acho que já foi sugerido e descartado.

Comment: Eu uso um [comentário enlatado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6972/137387) na maioria das vezes funciona.

Comment: @AugustoVasques O comentário enlatado funciona algumas vezes, mas depende de alguém ir lá e comentar. Só que muitas vezes o AP comenta "funcionou" e some, então nunca verá o comentário nem aceitará a resposta. O ideal é que a interface do site ajudasse e guiasse o usuário, o que já foi sugerido trocentas vezes ([exemplo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803)) e nunca é atendido...

Comment: Com certeza uma coisa integrada na interface seria melhor, mas com a SE já descartou....temos caçar com gato.