# Como fazer a comunidade votar mais?

Tags: debate, votos

Estava dando uma olhada nas perguntas feitas para os candidatos a moderador responder, e uma delas estava falando sobre [como a comunidade vota  menos.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8406/195519)

- Seria interessante para o site adicionar um prêmio de reputação sempre que um usúario mais novo vota?
   Como `+1` de reputação para ele, com algumas restrições exemplo:

> - Votar no máximo 10 vezes.
> - Os votos não derem pontos para as perguntas/resposta.
> - Apenas usúarios entre `15 - 50` se encaixariam nesse projeto.

Assim como as edições dão `+2` até você ter `2000`, na minha visão isso faria com que os usúarios se acostumarem a votar mais.

Comment: Já existe medalha para isso em vários níveis de votação. E não tem atraído as pessoas. Quando atrai, geralmente a pessoa vota a esmo sem qualquer critério, então é mais um malefício do que benefício.

Comment: Entendi, você teria alguma ideia para tentar resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não, afinal, se eu tivesse, eu já teria debatido e/ou implementado.

Comment: Relacionados: 
 [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente), [Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/devemos-pedir-para-aceitar-resposta),
 [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) e [Vamos fazer uma campanha para incentivar as pessoas a votarem?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2510/vamos-fazer-uma-campanha-para-incentivar-as-pessoas-a-votarem)

Comment: Não acho que isso seja a solução. Se hoje já temos distorções (gente que vota em código que nem compila ou cheio de gambiarras e falhas graves como SQL injection, ou usa voto como "like" só porque achou legal, mesmo que não responda a pergunta, etc), imagina se dar pontos pra quem vota, aí que as pessoas votarão ainda mais sem critério nenhum. E o problema não é só nos usuários novos, tem usuário com mais de 1000 pontos que nunca deu um voto sequer, ou deu bem menos do que recebeu. Não sei qual a solução, mas acho que dar pontos pra quem vota não resolve e pode até piorar...

Comment: A empresa dona do SOpt possui uma [ferramenta de Q&A paga](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) e está usando o sites da [Comunidade Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) como vitrine para atrair compradores. Só que isso está fazendo que o nosso site que era frequentado por pessoas mais engajadas na vida profissional e ou acadêmica fosse popularizado. [Usuário popular em informática](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/C/code-monkey.html) não é relacionado a fator econômico ou nível de aprendizado formal, aqui no site há autodidatas que são usuários de elite. Os falta ler regras.

Comment: Votar pouco não é um problema, pelo menos não um grande, pelo menos não hoje. Atualmente, a maioria das novas perguntas são ruins e fechadas. Resolver o problema da qualidade das perguntas seria mais importante e, provavelmente, mais efetivo, se houver um bom conteúdo (nas novas perguntas), possivelmente haja mais votos, além de trazer de volta usuários mais engajados que [praticamente] abandonaram a comunidade e fazer com que outros sejam mais ativos

Comment: Particularmente, se eu fosse trazer uma proposta para "aumento dos votos", daria uma estudada no SOru e SOes. Tanto em estatísticas quanto no tipo de pergunta que é feito por lá. Creio que nossos escopos sejam similares (não tenho certeza). O que já notei é que a base de usuários ativos lá parece ser maior (pelo menos no SOru)

Comment: @RafaelTavares o SOru originalmente não era um site da StackExchange, era um site "concorrente" chamado `Hashcode.ru` (criado pelo Nicolas Chabanovsky, esse hoje é funcionário da Stack Overflow), criado entre 2010 e 2011. Esse site é mais antigo que os SOes, SOja e SOpt, então não é bem alguma estratégia para atrair público, é mais pelo tempo de existência.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não sabia que o "SOru" era main antigo, interessante!