# Quanto tempo sem dedicar a própria pergunta passar ser um comportamento negativo?

Tags: debate

As vezes fazemos uma pergunta e logo em seguida ocorrem fatos que nos impede dedicar uma atenção adequada as respostas datas, ou mesmo não há como fazermos testes com a respostas datas para analisar melhor se devemos apontá-la como solução. Sem falar nos casos que precisamos aprofundar no assunto para melhorar a análise da própria resposta.

E ai quanto tempo os membros e moderadores podem considerar que tal comportamento é negativo?

Comment: Acho justo ao menos o AP fazer um comentário que irá fazer os testes assim que possível, porque muitas vezes eu coloco uma resposta lá e não sei se a pessoa viu, ou abandonou o SO

Answer (score 10):

Não existe resposta "científica" pra isso. Eu acho que esse tempo é proporcional à participação de quem fez a pergunta na comunidade. Se é um usuário conhecido, que sempre é visto no site e/ou chat, o tempo tende a ser maior, pois as pessoas têm alguma segurança de que alguma hora a pessoa vai aparecer e dar algum retorno. Com usuários novos e/ou menos conhecidos, a paciência tende a ser menor, mas ainda assim varia de pessoa para pessoa. De qualquer maneira, como regra geral, eu diria que é aceitável aguardar alguns dias antes que qualquer resposta seja marcada como aceita. Sobre isso, ver a seguinte discussão: *[Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas?lq=1)*